# Binary logging in MySQL

Tags: mysql, configuration, binary-log

Here is my.ini

```
# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

I'm trying to binary logging of mysql database.

Please suggest me to enable binary logging in MySQL Version 5.5.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the configuration variable for enabling binary logging.

Did you restart the MySQL service? The service won't re-read the my.ini until you restart.

You can check that it's writing binary logs with the MySQL statement `SHOW BINARY LOGS`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bill is right.. You did the right thing but if you did not restart your MySQL service it will not take effect.